# Pull all reports filtering by a certain field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, rest, soql, workbench

Is there a way to pull all active reports in Salesforce that filter by a certain field?

I tried using a rest API in workbench "/services/data/v50.0/analytics/reports", but it still seems like I have to manually step into the describe URL for each report (there are a lot) and then manually search for a filter. It's also not exactly easy to read.

Is there a better way to do this?

EX:

Find all reports using TEAM as a filter